# Microsoft Graph API filter and select on messages/attachements

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Currently I'm trying to visualize mails from outlook within my own web client. So I'm receiving all mails through the graph api by calling:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/
```

After selecting a mail I'll get the content by calling:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message.id}
```

That gives me the mail itself and by using [message](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message)/[body](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/itembody)/content I can visualize the mail for the user.

The message itself can contain inline images (by using a `cid:` within the img tag). In that case the image is available as an attachment of the mail. And all attachments can be accessed by calling:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message.id}/attachments
```

Unfortunately I'd like to only get the content of these attachments that are needed to visualize the mail (some logos, etc.) and not the also attached PowerPoint-Presentation. If we take a first look on what we get on the above call, it looks quite easy to fulfill the desired behaviour:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('{user-id}')/messages('message-id')/attachments",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            "id": "{attachment-id}",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-03-12T14:08:56Z",
            "name": "justSomeFileName.jpg",
            "contentType": "image/jpeg",
            "size": 3049,
            "isInline": true,
            "contentId": "ii_jek0lxzn0_1620b160dff814aa",
            "contentLocation": null,
            "contentBytes": "{base64 string length:3736}"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            "id": "{attachment-id}",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-03-12T14:07:38Z",
            "name": "my presentation.pptx",
            "contentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
            "size": 184754,
            "isInline": false,
            "contentId": "CA6D0D1EAE042D4A81A110524C30BF01@eurprd03.prod.outlook.com",
            "contentLocation": null,
            "contentBytes": "{base64 string length:245704}"
        }
    ]
}
```

### But here is my problem:

To get only the really needed attachments to visualize the mail with pictures I tried several queries, but all without success:

- Get all where `IsInline equals true`:

  ```
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message.id}/attachments/?$filter=isInline eq true
  ```

  The most obvious one. Unfortunately it returns **all** attachments without applying any filtering.
- Get all, but use select to get only id and contentId:

  ```
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message.id}/attachments/?$select=id,contentId
  ```

  Not that effective, cause we have to make two calls (another one to get the content by calling `/messages/{message.id}/attachments/{attachment-id}`), but better then nothing. Unfortunately this returns the following error message:

  > "Could not find a property named 'contentId' on type 'microsoft.graph.attachment'."
- Get all attachments with all properties except `contentBytes`:

  For this I didn't find anything within the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters). So maybe something like `$except=contentBytes` to get only the meta informations of all attachments without the concrete data itself.

So, exists there any method to filter attachments on properties of type `#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment` or to get the meta informations of all attachments without the property `contentBytes`?